# What benefit if any does the player level have in DoTA 2?

Tags: dota-2

Just wondering how the level that you gain from battle points affects the game, if at all.  Is it just an e-peen thing?  Is it a match-making thing?

Comment: Means absolutely nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only known difference would be that, each time you level up, you get a random item.

---

But yeah it can definitely be an "e-peen" thing, seeing as they're public, and *you get more points for wins*.  With some thinking you can guess that the level 10 guy with 100 wins probably doesn't have as many losses (and subsequently higher e-peen) as the level 10 guy with 60 wins (because he has a lot of losses to make up for the difference in won games).

Comment: Valve has confirmed that player level is not factored into matchmaking: http://dev.dota2.com/showthread.php?t=29937

Comment: Using level to guess about win rates is not very reliable, since the beta was open for a very long time before experience was added.  Personally I had over 100 wins before experience was added to the game.

Comment: Also, not that its that big, but playing bot games will not count "wins" but do give you battle points.

Answer (score 1):

Profile levels have a few functions in Dota 2. They determine the tiers of items you are eligible to drop after a match, and for every level up, you will gain a guaranteed new cosmetic item. Certain queues are also enabled depending on your profile level, such as Ranked matchmaking which is enabled at level 13.